# Order By Last in SQL: Force a value to be last in the order

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

In SQL, I have used

```
...ORDER BY name DESC NULLS LAST
```

which works quite awesome, yet is there any way that I can set a specific value to be last? Such as an empty string (@EMPTY).

```
...ORDER BY name DESC (@EMPTY) LAST
```

I am dynamically building SQL off of user choices on a table, and when the user changes the sort order, I change my sort order in my SQL. Also, the user can choose which column to sort by. The column that I am sorting by will either be type `text` or type `int`. I don't need any fancy `ORDER BY` when `column` is type `int`, but I do need to force all values of `""` to the end of the `ORDER BY` when the `type` of the `column` is `text`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a `case` as the first element in the sort order:

```
order by
    case when name = '' then 1 else 0 end
,   name desc
```

Comment: hmm... will this work though since `name` is type `text`? If I cast `1` or `0` as `name`, the column types won't match. Good attempt though! I'll try it.

Comment: This answer is sorting on two different columns.  The first one has an integer type, the second one a text type.

Comment: @WebWanderer yes this works because you are comparing name (string) to empty string so types do match, you are then returning an entirely new thing based on that comparison which is used to sort your results.